# Blank desktop in Linux Mint 15 Xfce

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Some days ago, I installed Linux Mint 15 "olivia" Xfce in my pc. but, today when I 
started it everything was working fine but, the desktop color is grey and nothing 
but a blank screen. when I click on it nothing happens. I can use the taskbar start any application and yes i am writing this from Linux Mint.
I am also giving a screenshot
[image: this is how desktop looks like]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like your window manager is not running. This should solve it:

```
xfwm4 --replace &
```

If that does solve it, just save your session and exit so that next time it will be loaded automatically.